# web-scraping: web-scraped object doesn't match information on the website and crashes RStudio

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, division, rvest

I collected a series of URLs similar to [this one](https://www.veterinaire.fr/annuaires/trouver-un-veterinaire-pour-soigner-mon-animal.html?tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40extension%5D=SiteVeterinaire&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40vendor%5D=SiteVeterinaire&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40controller%5D=FrontendUser&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40action%5D=search&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5Barguments%5D=YToxOntzOjY6InNlYXJjaCI7YTo1OntzOjM6Im5vbSI7czowOiIiO3M6NjoicmVnaW9uIjtzOjA6IiI7czoxMToiZGVwYXJ0ZW1lbnQiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjU6InZpbGxlIjtzOjA6IiI7czoxMjoiaXRlbXNQZXJQYWdlIjtzOjI6IjEwIjt9fQ%3D%3D21a1899f9a133814dfc1eb4e01b3b47913bd9925&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40request%5D=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22%40extension%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22SiteVeterinaire%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22%40controller%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22FrontendUser%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22%40action%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22search%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22%40vendor%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22SiteVeterinaire%22%3B%7D7cd75ca141359a98763248c24da8103293a53d08&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__trustedProperties%5D=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22search%22%3Ba%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A3%3A%22nom%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A6%3A%22region%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A11%3A%22departement%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A5%3A%22ville%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A12%3A%22itemsPerPage%22%3Bi%3A1%3B%7D%7D86c9510d17c093c44d053714ab20567929a45f9d&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bnom%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregion%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bdepartement%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bville%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5BitemsPerPage%5D=100&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B%40widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=127&cHash=8d8dc78e004b4b9d0ecfdf9b884f54ca). For each URL, I am using the `rvest` package to web-scrape information related to the address of every practitioner listed in each box of the webpage. By inspecting the HTML structure of the webpage, I could notice that the information I am trying to retrieve is present inside the HTML division called `unit size1of2` (which appears, by hovering with the cursor, as `div.unit.size1of2`). Then, I used the following code to extract the information I need:

```
library(rvest)
library(xlm2)

webpage <- read_html(x = "myURL")

webpage_name <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("div.unit.size1of2") %>%
  html_text(trim = T)
```

However, when I extract the information, the result I get it's super messy. First of all, there are information I didn't want to scrape, some of them seems to not even be present on the website. In addition, my RStudio IDE freezes for a while, and every time I try to output the result, without working properly afterwards with any command. Finally, the result is not the one I was looking for.

Do you think this is due to some kind of protection present on the website?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I had a look at the website, but it appears to be unremarkable.  [This](https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fwww.veterinaire.fr%2f) is its technology profile.  Perhaps it's dynamically creating its content, which means you would need to run it in a Javascript engine to get the actual data, or find the origin JSON endpoint and get the data from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Do you have any idea on how to proceed with your solution. I have never run anything in a Javascript engine or looked for the JSON endpoint. I would not know from where to start. Thanks again!

Comment: I would start by examining the traffic using WireShark, Telerik Fiddler or a similar tool.  It will tell you whether a JSON endpoint is in play.

Comment: Your selector is too general.  Try `html_nodes(".search-result div.unit.size1of2")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start iterating on rows which can be selected using `div.search-result .line` and then :

- getting the name using `div:first-child h3`
- getting the ordinal using `div:first-child p`
- getting the location by iterating on `div:nth-child(2) p` since there can be multiple locations (one has 5 locations on your page) and store them in a list

It's necessary to remove the tabs and new lines using `gsub("[\t\n]", "", x)` for the name and ordinal. For the addresses, you can get the text and split according to new line `\n`, remove duplicates new line and strip the first and  last line to have a list like :

```
[1] "CABINET VÉTÉRINAIRE DV FEYS JEAN-MARC"
[2] "Cabinet Veterinaire"                  
[3] "ZA de Kercadiou"                      
[4] "XXXXX"                                
[5] "LANVOLLON"                            
[6] "Tél : 0X.XX.XX.XX.XX"
```

The following code also converts the list of vectors to a dataframe with all the data on that page :

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)

url = "https://www.veterinaire.fr/annuaires/trouver-un-veterinaire-pour-soigner-mon-animal.html?tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40extension%5D=SiteVeterinaire&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40vendor%5D=SiteVeterinaire&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40controller%5D=FrontendUser&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40action%5D=search&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5Barguments%5D=YToxOntzOjY6InNlYXJjaCI7YTo1OntzOjM6Im5vbSI7czowOiIiO3M6NjoicmVnaW9uIjtzOjA6IiI7czoxMToiZGVwYXJ0ZW1lbnQiO3M6MDoiIjtzOjU6InZpbGxlIjtzOjA6IiI7czoxMjoiaXRlbXNQZXJQYWdlIjtzOjI6IjEwIjt9fQ%3D%3D21a1899f9a133814dfc1eb4e01b3b47913bd9925&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__referrer%5D%5B%40request%5D=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22%40extension%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22SiteVeterinaire%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22%40controller%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22FrontendUser%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22%40action%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22search%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22%40vendor%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22SiteVeterinaire%22%3B%7D7cd75ca141359a98763248c24da8103293a53d08&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B__trustedProperties%5D=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22search%22%3Ba%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A3%3A%22nom%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A6%3A%22region%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A11%3A%22departement%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A5%3A%22ville%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A12%3A%22itemsPerPage%22%3Bi%3A1%3B%7D%7D86c9510d17c093c44d053714ab20567929a45f9d&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bnom%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregion%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bdepartement%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5Bville%5D=&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5Bsearch%5D%5BitemsPerPage%5D=100&tx_siteveterinaire_general%5B%40widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=127&cHash=8d8dc78e004b4b9d0ecfdf9b884f54ca"

rows <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("div.search-result .line")

strip <- function (x) gsub("[\t\n]", "", x)

i <- 1
data = list()
for(r in rows){
    addresses = list()
    j <- 1
    locations = r %>% html_nodes("div:nth-child(2) p")
    for(loc in locations){
        addresses[[j]] <- loc %>% html_text() %>% 
            gsub("[\t]", "", .) %>%  #remove tabs
            gsub('([\n])\\1+', '\\1', .) %>% #remove duplicate \n
            gsub('^\n|\n$', '', .) %>% #remove 1st and last \n
            strsplit(., split='\n', fixed=TRUE) #split by \n
        j <- j + 1 
    }
    data[[i]] <- c(
        name = r %>% html_nodes("div:first-child h3") %>% html_text() %>% strip(.),
        ordinal = r %>% html_nodes("div:first-child p") %>% html_text() %>% strip(.),
        addresses = addresses
    )
    i <- i + 1
}

df = rbind.fill(lapply(data,function(y){as.data.frame(t(y),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))

#show data
print(df)
for(i in 1:3){
    print(paste("name",df[i,"name"]))
    print(paste("ordinal",df[i,"ordinal"]))
    print(paste("addresses",df[i,"addresses"]))
    print(paste("addresses1",df[i,"addresses1"]))
    print(paste("addresses2",df[i,"addresses2"]))
    print(paste("addresses3",df[i,"addresses3"]))
}
```

Comment: Hey Bertrand, thanks a lot for your detailed and prompt answer. It was super helpful! This question has been closed because, apparently, needs debugging detailed. Do you know what can I do to improve it? Should I had the desired behaviour? Thanks!